# type error: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, module, typeerror

I just started using python and I get an error when I try to copy an object:

```
import numpy
import copy

c = numpy.zeros(10)
t = copy(c)
```

Running the code I encountered this error that I can not solve, could you help me? Thank you all

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sage_server.py", line 5, in <module>
    t = copy(c)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: How are you running this code?  Is it saved to a file or are you running in interactive mode?

Comment: I'm runnung it in interactive mode

Comment: `t=copy(c)` calls the `copy` module. Perhaps you wanted `copy.copy()`?

Comment: Try `t = c.copy()`. The copy method can be called on numpy arrays without having to import the module

Answer (score 1):

You might be invoking a module as a function (as suggested by the error message).

```
>>> import copy
>>> type(copy)
<type 'module'>
```

Instead, what you seem to need is the [copy()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy) function, that is included in that module.

```
>>> type(copy.copy)
<type 'function'>
```

For that, you would need to do something like:

```
>>> copy.copy(c)
```

Comment: Note that `numpy` arrays have a `copy()` method: `%timeit b=arr.copy()
1.06 µs ± 5.75 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)` vs `%timeit b = copy.copy(arr)
2.28 µs ± 13.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)` for a 1000-element array

Comment: @roganjosh yup yup - that copy func is optimized for numpy arrays; I viewed this as the OP having a syntax/lower level issue, hence taking this approach. thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: Yeah, you were right to address the specific issue in the question, I just thought it was worth adding :)

Comment: @Francesca It would be nice, if you could accept/upvote an answer if your issue is resolved, or close to a resolution. From [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."